# Apply CIFilters on UI elements

Tags: swift, calayer, core-image

I want to apply an CIFilter on an UI element. I tried to apply it onto the views layer via the .filters member. However the filter won`t get applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach: use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` to generate a `UIImage`, apply the filter to that and overlay an image view containing the filtered image over your original component.

Here's a way to do that with a blur ([taken from my blog](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/applying-gaussian-blur-to-uiviews-with.html)):

Getting a blurred representation of a UIView is pretty simple: I need to begin an image context, use the view's layer's renderInContext method to render into the context and then get a UIImage from the context:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height), false, 1)

layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()


UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Once I have the image populated, it's a fairly standard workflow to apply a Gaussian blur to it:

```
guard let blur = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") else
{
    return
}

blur.setValue(CIImage(image: image), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
blur.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

let ciContext  = CIContext(options: nil)

let result = blur.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!

let boundingRect = CGRect(x: -blurRadius * 4,
    y: -blurRadius * 4,
    width: frame.width + (blurRadius * 8),
    height: frame.height + (blurRadius * 8))

let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(result, fromRect: boundingRect)


let filteredImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
```

A blurred image will be larger than its input image, so I need to be explicit about the size I require in `createCGImage`.

The next step is to add a `UIImageView` to my view and hide all the other views. I've subclassed `UIImageView` to `BlurOverlay` so that when it comes to removing it, I can be sure I'm not removing an existing `UIImageView`:

```
let blurOverlay = BlurOverlay()
blurOverlay.frame = boundingRect

blurOverlay.image = filteredImage

subviews.forEach{ $0.hidden = true }


addSubview(blurOverlay)
```

When it comes to de-blurring, I want to ensure the last subview is one of my `BlurOverlay` remove it and unhide the existing views:

```
func unBlur()
{
    if let blurOverlay = subviews.last as? BlurOverlay
    {
        blurOverlay.removeFromSuperview()

        subviews.forEach{ $0.hidden = false }
    }

}
```

Finally, to see if a `UIView` is currently blurred, I just need to see if its last subview is a `BlurOverlay`:

```
var isBlurred: Bool
{
    return subviews.last is BlurOverlay
}
```

Comment: Trank you for your answer. That's exactly what I want to do. I need to apply a filter (perspective transformation) on a MKMapView. What would you recommend to do then. The user interaction does not need to be there. I think of never adding the MapView to the View and simply getting an image of it as you said. However I will rotate the MapView programmatically so it should have a certain frame rate while moving. How can I get more images while moving the view?

Comment: If you're looking to rotate the image in 3D, why not use the image as the diffuse contents for a SceneKit material applied to a plane? If you want to animate the points of a perspective transform, take a look at `CADisplayLink` (but I think you'll get funkier results with SceneKit :) ).

Comment: I wil rotate the MapView around a geographical coordinate. And the rotation around the coordinate should be shown with an applied filter. A simple image wouldn't do the trick in this case. What would you suggest to do for being able to show a rotation which the MapView manages by itself with an applied CIFilter? It is like applying a CIFilter on a video but in my case it is an animation from the MapView itself that I want to show. I would need sth. like the PixelBuffer. Unfortunately I think it is not possible to set one for a MapView.

Comment: Hi - I think you need to create a new question for this.